# Test suites info in PHPUnit bootstrap file

Tags: phpunit

I am running test using a `phpunit.xml.dist` file. This file defines several test suites and specifies a bootstrap.php. In this bootstrap.php I am currently loading all dependencies for all tests.

A small subset of the tests is dependent on some third party library, which is optional. These tests are all part of a particular test suite. So I only want to load this library in the bootstrapping file when that particular test suite is specified.

How can I determine if this test suite was specified? This then ensures that most tests can be run when the library is not loaded, and that one can easily verify the code and tests that should not depend on the library indeed do not need it.

I currently have the following. Is there something better?

```
if ( !in_array( '--testsuite=WikibaseDatabaseStandalone', $GLOBALS['argv'] ) ) {
    require_once( __DIR__ . '/evilMediaWikiBootstrap.php' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature request on the PHPUnit bugtracker for a test suite specific bootstrap is here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/733

For now there are two options: One is yours which is fine but feels really hackish and doesn't work out well if you run "all the tests" if you have specific bootstrap for every one of them.

My suggestion would be to write a test listener and hook into "startTestSuite" and "endTestSuite". This is a nice maintained and BC compatible way to execute code only when the test suite is actually started and you can also clean up afterwards.

See http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener and http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners for how to include the test listener.

Answer (score 0):

One of the usual way to handle this is to check if a required dependency is installed, and if not, run

```
$this->markTestAsSkipped('lib not installed');
```

That skipping can also happen in the `setUp()` phase of a test.

Finally, you can add `@group` annotations to the test-class and/or test functions to give some choice to whether or not the test is run from the command line (with the `--group [names...]` parameter).

Finally, an option that has also been used in the ZendFramework is to only add the TestSuite that runs a subset within a larger set of a testsuite - in code. There is an example of being able to

- **a)** turn off as will,
- **b)** turn off if the extension is not loaded, or
- **c)** run the tests, for the use of (for example)

  [caching with APC](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/tests/Zend/Cache/AllTests.php#L98)